# Tablet Android application resolution is breaking in smartphone

Tags: android, tablet, smartphone

I have created an android application for tablet, the application is having big table with 15 columns. The application is working fine and the table seems okay in tablet. The issue is that when I open the application in smart phone the table  resolution is breaking.

I have seems many application which works fine in both smartphone and tablet.
I am new to android programming, Can anyone please tell me some solution how to achieve the resolution issue. Do I need to create separate application for smartphone and tablet

[image]

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/oil" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText03"
                style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText02"
                style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password6"
                style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Person Names"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Employee No"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Result in Entra"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Current Status"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Image Upload"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Remark"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Actions"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post some screenshots and some xml code?

Comment: @pgiitu I have posted an example code

Comment: check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the 'values' folder to set the dimensions and accordingly to the layout for different screen size devices.
And you can also use the 'layout' folder with different screen sizes and create your layout accordingly.

for more information you can use layout folders like this,

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Comment: what if I do If I have a large table

Comment: For a large table, use a ScrollView or two (assuming that's what you want the user to be able to do on their phone).

Comment: if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in /layout-sw600dp. Like this it you know the dp(Density Pixel) of the screensize you can put ur layout in that folder.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I have posted the code, do we need to give scroll to vertical and horizontal

Comment: For this kind of layout, yes StephanBranczy K is right. You should use horizontal scrollview. Or if possible than give the landscape orieantation to this particular activity so even for mobile device it will look fine.

Comment: @HardikChauhan can you give me an example for that

Comment: See the edited answer for using the different layout folders.

Comment: @HardikChauhan So I need to define the font size, images also within different layout.xml. Any suggestion to give me for this table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91882/discussion-between-hardik-chauhan-and-alex-man).

Comment: @HardikChauhan hi, did you get time to take a look on that

Comment: @HardikChauhan I am getting some warnings

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a CardView in Android.
You can have your custom adapter and can display the data.